# SQL : Deleting records found using 3 joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-delete

I am using SQL Server 2014 database, and SQL Server Management Studio to create and run queries.

Tables are :

Persons

```
| ID | personName |
+----+------------+
| 1  |    Hamish  |
| 2  |    Morag   |
| 3  |    Ewan    |
```

Cars

```
| ID | CarName |
+----+---------+
| 1  |  Humber |
| 2  |  Austen |
| 3  |  Morris |
```

Gadgets

```
| ID | GadgetName |
+----+------------+
| 1  |  Cassette  |
| 2  |     CD     |
| 3  |   Radio    |
```

CarToPersonMap

```
| ID | CarID | PersonID |
+----+-------+----------+
| 1  |   1   |    1     |
```

CarToGadgetMap

```
| ID | CarID | GadgetID |
+----+-------+----------+
| 1  |   2   |    2     |
```

The map tables have the appropriate foreign keys.

I want to delete records where a `Car` exists but is unused. So in the example above I want to delete `Car` with `ID = 3`.

I have a `SELECT` statement that uses 3 `JOIN`s as follows. The statement works and it returns the correct row(s), i.e. `Car` with `ID = 3`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT Cars.*
     FROM Cars 
     LEFT JOIN CarToGadgetMap ON Cars.ID = CarToGadgetMap.CarID
     WHERE CarToGadgetMap.CarID IS NULL) t1
JOIN
    (SELECT Cars.*
     FROM Cars 
     LEFT JOIN PersonToCarMap ON Cars.ID = PersonToCarMap.CarID
     WHERE PersonToCarMap.CarID IS NULL) t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

When I attempt a `DELETE` using the code below, it deletes all 3 `Car` rows:

```
DELETE Cars 
FROM
    (SELECT Cars.*
     FROM Cars 
     LEFT JOIN CarToGadgetMap ON Cars.ID = CarToGadgetMap.CarID
     WHERE CarToGadgetMap.CarID IS NULL) t1
JOIN
    (SELECT Cars.*
     FROM Cars 
     LEFT JOIN PersonToCarMap ON Cars.ID = PersonToCarMap.CarID
     WHERE PersonToCarMap.CarID IS NULL) t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Result message:

```
(3 row(s) affected)
```

and inspection shows all 3 rows in the `Cars` table have been deleted.

Why do all records get deleted, when the `SELECT` statement returns just 1 row?

Can anyone help, please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by just using this code. I tested it by creating a database & data at my end.

```
 DELETE Cars
 FROM Cars 
 LEFT JOIN CarToPersonMap ON Cars.ID = CarToPersonMap.CarID
 LEFT JOIN CarToGadgetMap ON Cars.ID = CarToGadgetMap.CarID
 WHERE CarToPersonMap.CarID IS NULL and  CarToGadgetMap.CarID IS NULL
```

Comment: Excellent @Raju.  A lot cleaner code too.  And the SELECT version of this gives me all columns from all 3 tables, whereas my version returned 2 sets of the columns from the Cars table. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a WHERE clause instead of FROM.

```
DELETE cars WHERE cars.id = 3 (Get your query select only the id from your logic, rather than selecting all the tables with cars.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a `DELETE` or `UPDATE` statement, the table to modify is calculated as follows:

- Look at the `FROM` clause (in `DELETE` this is the second `FROM`) for a top-level table aliased with that name.
- Otherwise, look for a single top-level reference to `Cars` even with an alias
- Otherwise cross-join the table `Cars` with the whole `FROM` clause

The problem with your `DELETE` is that the top-level scope has no table named or aliased as `Cars`, so it's in effect just doing a big cross-join on the whole `Cars` table.

You can do this instead like this

```sql
DELETE Cars
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM CarToPersonMap cpm ON Cars.ID = cpm.CarID)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM CarToGadgetMap cgm ON Cars.ID = cgm.CarID);
```

You can also specify explicitly a second `FROM` clause

```sql
DELETE Cars
FROM Cars
WHERE ...
```